# Routing IP with route ADD Windows command and 2 networks

Tags: networking, ip, routing, mask

I have 2 networks

NETWORK 1 defined by 192.168.1.1 to 254 (gateway)

NETWORK 2 defined by 192.168.42.1 to 254(gateway DLINK routeur)

One of my PC is in NETWORK 2 with IP Static adress 192.168.42.17

The DLink Router is also on NETWORK 1 with a static IP Address : 192.168.1.86

My PC is on NETWORK 1 with IP Adress 192.168.1.27

I have tried to define a route on my PC with

route add 192.168.42.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.86 -p

but My PC on NETWORK 1 cannot ping the other on NETWORK 2

My route print is

IPv4 Table de routage

===========================================================================

Itinéraires actifs :

Destination réseau    Masque réseau  Adr. passerelle   Adr. interface Métrique

```
      0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1     192.168.1.27     35 <p>

    127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331 <p>

    127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331 <p>
```

127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331

```
  192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.1.27    291 <p>

 192.168.1.27  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.27    291 <p>

192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.27    291 <p>

 192.168.42.0    255.255.255.0     192.168.1.86     192.168.1.27     37 <p>

    224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331 <p>

    224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.1.27    291 <p>
```

255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331

255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.27    291

===========================================================================

Do you have any idea ? Thanks in advance !! Regards

Comment: You need to better explain “my dlink router is also on network 1” how is it physically hooked up? I’m assuming this is a basic home router.

Comment: Yep its a basic DLINK N300 router and Linked to the NETWORK 1 by an ethernet cable